# How to change text inside a div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div structured like this `<div class="pin">CODE# 1234</div>` and now how to replace "1234" with my new value using jquery?

Answer (score 3):

you can do

```
$('.pin').text(function(idx, value){
    return value.replace(/\d+$/, 'newvalue')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s9YnW/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text().replace("1234", "new Val")`:

```
var oldText = $(".pin").text();
$(".pin").text(oldText.replace("1234", "New Value"));
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EJAGU/)

Another solution would be to use a span:

```
<div class="pin">CODE# <span class="value">1234<span></div>
```

and js:

```
$(".value").text("newValue");
```

Comment: @JezD The OP didn't ask this. Simply replace a text into div.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `replace` like

```
$(".pin").text().replace("1234", "MYValue");
```

Or try like(May be it works but not sure)

```
var txt = $('.pin').text();
txt_arr = txt.split(' ');    //txt.split('#'); even
txt_arr[1] = newValue;
$('.pin').text(txt_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="pin">CODE# <span class="code_value">1234<span></div>

$(".pin").find('.code_value').text().replace("1234", "New Value");
```

or

```
$(".pin").find('.code_value').html("New Value");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a function:

```
function replaceCode(codeToFind, codeToReplace) {
    $("div:contains('CODE# "+codeToFind+"')").text(function (_, value) {
        return value.replace('CODE# '+codeToFind, 'CODE# '+codeToReplace);
    });
}

replaceCode(1234, 9999);
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/9tdjt/1/).

Starting HTML for example above:

```
<div class="pin">CODE# 1234</div>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<div class="pin">CODE# 9999</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this.

`$(function(){
$('.pin').text('').text('1234')
});`

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution to this would be

```
function changePinValue(pin) {
   $('.pin').html("CODE# "+pin);
}
```

Happy Coding..